# How to use ReportViewer vs Two methods in VB.Net 2010

Tags: vb.net, report-viewer2010

Now I have a problem with ReportViewer, I have built two queries by using ADO.Net tool. In DataSet Designer(MytableAdapter), I added 2 queries and gave the different method names, I want to view both queries in ReportViewer but I can only view one query, so please kindly help me to show them all.

Thank in advance.
Regards,
Pheakdei

Comment: The data source for your report will be a `DataTable`.  You simply fill that `DataTable` using the whichever query you want to display the results of at the time.

Comment: I did that but it displayed only one query. When I View My DataSet it contains only first query I don't know why.

Comment: If the `DataTable` only contains the results from one of the queries it's because you only called the method that corresponds to one of the queries.  If you want the results of the other query then you have to call the other method.